# How many accounts could send cloudwatch events to AWS logs destination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to have a central account processing cloudwatch logs. (Cross account logs forwarding)

Following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CreateDestination.html

> After step 7a is complete, in the log data recipient account,
> associate an access policy with the destination. This policy enables
> the log data sender account (111111111111) to access the destination
> in the log data recipient account (999999999999).

There is a limitation * is not possible to  be defined in Priciple AWS accounts.

> If multiple accounts are sending logs to this destination, each sender
> account must be listed separately in the policy. This policy does not
> support specifying * as the Principal or the use of the
> aws:PrincipalOrgId global key.

**Is there any limitation of how many accounts could be granted/attached using access policy ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [resource policies for cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_ResourcePolicy.html) your only limit is a max policy document length of 5120 characters.  Depending on the number of accounts and the size/maturity of your organization I would recommend configuring [aws organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/organizations.html).  With aws organizations you can use the principleOrgID condition key in the resource policy to grant any account in your organization permissions to write logs.  More information on that strategy can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/control-access-to-aws-resources-by-using-the-aws-organization-of-iam-principals/).

Comment: You can't use principleOrgID for log destinations

Comment: We are using aws:PrincipalOrgPaths instead of principalOrgID the way we can seperate logs coming from different environments "DEV, QUAL and PROD". each of our environments is a standalone Organizational Unit